# Multiple ternary operators and evaluating int as boolean mystery

Tags: c#, int, boolean, ternary-operator

```
int cow;
int cow = true ? false ? false ? false ? 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7;
```

How does this ternary operator work?

Why does it give me the result it gives me?

People has clearly understood what was asked. Please give me more minus in reputation.

Comment: Nothing there is "evaluating int as boolean"! What's your question?

Comment: Please clarify by stating how you would expect that line to behave.

Comment: The code you gave me prints 6, changing the first `false` to `true' prints 5. I think you need to re-check your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does any combination of true and false return the value it does?

There is no combination of any boolean here. This [`?:` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) returns first or second expression, **not the condition itself**.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   first_expression is evaluated **and becomes the result**. If condition is
>   false, second_expression is evaluated **and becomes the result**.

Since this operator is [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators), your code works as;

```
true ? false ? false ? false ? 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7
```

evaluated as;

```
true ? false ? false ? (false ? 3 : 4) : 5 : 6 : 7
```

which evaluated as;

```
true ? false ? false ? 4 : 5 : 6 : 7
```

which evaluated as;

```
true ? false ? (false ? 4 : 5) : 6 : 7
```

which evaluated as;

```
true ? false ? 5 : 6 : 7
```

which evaluated as;

```
true ? (false ? 5 : 6) : 7
```

which evaluated as;

```
true ? 6 : 7
```

which returns `6`.

Comment: @MakerOfTheUnicake Glad to help. I hope I can give enough explanation to your question.

Comment: im going to go through it step by step and see if I get it, when I do ill mark as answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The C# ternary operator is syntactic sugar for an if statement.

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Here is the equivalent code without the use of the ternary.  It will always fall into the cow = 6 block.

```
        if (true)
        {
            if (false)
            {
                if (false)
                {
                    if (false)
                    {
                        cow = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cow = 4;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cow = 5;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cow = 6;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cow = 7;
        }
```

Comment: I hope looking at this as actual if statements makes it easier to understand.  Best of luck!

Comment: Yes it does, im writing them as if statements now! If I could I would chose your as a valid answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

If you had removed all the unreachable code, you'd end up with

```
cow = true ? 6 : 7;
```

And `6` will be your answer every time.

What was your question by the way?

Comment: How does this work is my question.